# The best ways to practice Magento 2 when not in work

Tags: magento2, best-practice

Any recommendations for how to practice Magento 2 when not working? i.e. it's easier when working as you're presented with real life task, issues, clients etc. but when practicing at home, I'm just not sure of the best way to keep harnessing and improving Magento 2 skills etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, magento has a lot of aspects, frontend, backend, architecture and each section needs its own research.

You can start as a newbie with following:

There are a lot of articles available you can read online specially weblogs, I suggest you study the following links:

https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/

https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/

Also following this YouTube channel really helped me:
https://www.youtube.com/c/AlaaAlMaliki

after you got comfortable you can study the dev docs:
https://devdocs.magento.com

after again you spent some time and got comfortable, look at the most voted users here on magento and look at their question and answers it is a great resource to see what skills you are missing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) my bad, I should have mentioned, I am not a newbie, rather I have been a backend developer for over 5 years now. My question was relating to the scenario as a freelancer such as when you have the spare time, what is the best way to further enhance your Magento skills as in my case, a backend developer. I like to work on real tasks but when I'm at home just practicing, I can't seem to think of anything new to work on without having a specific task in mind. I find it easier if I'm working on real client tasks etc.

Comment: you can apply for contract jobs, you will be a great help to most of companies if you agree on part time contracts.